# Where are these indestructible HTML borders coming from?

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

In a fundraising page I'm working on at https://cjshayward.com/these-are-a-few-of-my-favorite-things/, in the body of the post there is one portrait without any border, but once you get to the shuffled list of "favorite things," all of the product images have an eight-pixel-wide border that remains present after setting DIV, A, and IMG tags to have **inline** style of `border: 0 !important; margin: 0 !important; padding: 0 !important`.

I've also spent some time inspecting the page, and can't find anything that would be assigning borders to the images or immediate containers. (N.B. I think it's more likely a border than a background with padding: some images are partially transparent PNG's, and those let you see the background image through transparent parts of the PNG's.)

The page is part of a Wordpress site under a modification of the twentyseventeen theme.

What am I missing?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Comment: Right click on the image, click on "Inspect element". It'll show the CSS rules that apply to the image, and you can disable them one by one to see which one causes the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the box-shadow property

```
.entry-content a img, .widget a img {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 8px #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 8px #fff;
}
```

remove this from the css

it was just masquerading as a border :-)

Comment: Thank you; thanks to this answer I have a "Today I learned..." takeaway, that box-shadows can produce effects ordinarily expected from borders.

Comment: Glad I could help. :-). It was unexpected.

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answer if that was the solution ;-P